# Starting animation after X seconds in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, animation

Following the [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.animation.html),

A [normal animation](http://jsfiddle.net/abgcvqw3/45/) is working fine.

But an [animation with a delay](http://jsfiddle.net/abgcvqw3/46/) (parameter: start added to previous example) is not working.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: check the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/abgcvqw3/48/

Comment: Thanks :) but I don't see a delay before the animation. How will be a delay of 1"?

Comment: ah sry, my mistake. you're right. weird - could'nt get it work, too.

Comment: sounds like a possible bug report, if it's a function that's not working as it's supposed to =)

Comment: @SaultDon I filled a but :) https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3897 Thanks a lot!